# spl_autoload not calling second autoload function

Tags: php, spl

I have an spl_autoload being called but the problem is the second autoload does not execute and I can't figure out why. With this code this code the script should die. I remove classes from folder array, the autoload will work. My code looks like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On'); 
/*** nullify any existing autoloads ***/
spl_autoload_register(null, false);
/*** specify extensions that may be loaded ***/
spl_autoload_extensions('.php');

function dataLoader($class) {
    foreach (array(PV_CORE.DS.'data'.DS, PV_CORE.DS.'system'.DS, PV_CORE.DS.'cms'.DS, PV_CORE.DS.'util'.DS,PV_CORE.DS.'components'.DS, PV_CORE.DS.'template'.DS) as $folder){
        if (is_file($folder.$class.'.php')) {
            include_once $folder.$class.'.php';
        }
    }//end foreach
}

function testLoader($class) {
    die();
    $filename = $class. '.php';
    $file =PV_CORE.DS.'data'.DS.$filename;
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        return false;
    }
    require_once $file;
}

spl_autoload_register('dataLoader');
spl_autoload_register('testLoader');
```

Comment: Your functions are register: print_r( spl_autoload_functions() ); I didn't really get it what you try to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works but probably a misunderstanding.

Your functions are registered:

```
print_r( spl_autoload_functions() );
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => dataLoader
    [1] => testLoader
)
```

and if you initialize a class

```
$class_obj = new ClassName();
```

dataLoader will try to load the file:

```
$folder.ClassName.php
```

Your script will only load the second or any other registered function if he can't find the class in the first place.

So if you remove your $class in the function dataLoader __autoload wont find the class anymore in the first registered function so he will try to look up for it in the second registered function and so on.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that spl_autoload was loading all the closes, but it loads on demand when the class cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

you need to

return true; // if the class has loaded and you want that the autoload stack will be stopped

return false; // if the class has not loaded and you want to continue the execution of the autoload stack

inside your callbacks

hope this helps